# Can Filebot create subfolders based on artist or title names?

Tags: music

I've used MediaMonkey for music organizing for a long time, but I'm considering Filebot.

My music is organized like so:

```
Music/{ABC}/{A}/Adele/{Album Title [Release Year]}/01_{Song Title}
```

So I'm arranging by the first letter of the artist name (grouped into 3's ABC, DEF, GHI...or 0-9 for anything starting with a number or symbol),

then I break that down to the first letter of the artist: A (in this case)

then artist name, album with date, track number with 2 digits_Song Title

Is it possible to do this in Filebot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through all the examples, then you should find all the bits and pieces you need there:

https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2

e.g.

```
Music/{artist[0]}/{artist}/{album} {[y]}/{pi}_{t}
```

The `{ABC}` part will probably require a bit of code, because your code has to decide which chunk of letters goes into which folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Filebot** uses `Groovy Regular Expressions` to rename any type of file, overwise you can use **Java** `String class methods` such as `replace`, `replaceAll`, or `Matcher class methods`.

In your case it might be a little complicated, but it is not a problem, I think..

Yes, it is possible.